# Filing in multiple countries with the same law firm and attorney

Tags: patent-applications, international, attorney

The question is, is there a cost benefit to filing a patent application in multiple countries with the same law firm and attorney?

Let's suppose that I file in the USA and Canada. I use the same law firm. Because the application is already prepared in English for the USA, there isn't much work left to be done to draft essentially the same application for Canada. The drawings would be the same.

And thus, would it be right to conclude that there is some cost benefit here? I.e., the total cost should be cheaper than the cost of filing in the USA alone + the cost of filing in Canada alone.

Am I right in this assessment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a well drafted US application in hand, whomever you hired to file an application in Canada would charge less than if they had to draft it from scratch. And visa versa. If it is not the same firm they might need to study the application before filing it.

Comment: Do you have an estimate of how much less, in percentages? Maybe 50% of the cost of filing from scratch, yada yada?

Comment: I would guess it was closer to 20%

Comment: To be clear, do you mean 20% X (cost of filing from scratch)? In other words, if the cost of filing from scratch is $10,000, then the cost of filing from a previously drafted application would be $2,000 = .2 X $10,000?

Comment: Yes that’s what I meant and it is a rough guess